# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Animation

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL ES 2.0 and Android, and I'm trying to make a live wallpaper. I'm currently trying to use a texture atlas to create animations and changing textures. I've looked everywhere, and [this tutorial](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-opengl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-7-texture-atlas/) is the most helpful thing I've found.

I understand how to load the texture atlas, but how would you change the texture object being rendered in the onDrawFrame method, so that it would be one square rendering the next texture every frame? What would the actual code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you have in that tutorial you can instead of filling up the uvBuffer (texCoord) buffer with random values, cycle through them each frame.
So lets say you start with UV(0,0), UV(0.25, 0), UV(0, 0.25) and UV(0.25, 0.25). Next frame, you change the values in the uvBuffer to UV(0.25, 0), UV(0.5, 0), UV(0.25, 0.25), UV(0.5, 0.25). And so on.

Solution 1:
Have a lookup array with all possible UV coordinates. Then use an int field to increase the step each frame. Put the next 4 items in a second array and replace the contents of the buffer.

Solution 2:
Store the 4 UV coordinates in an array and one float field for x-coord, one for y-coord.
Increase the x-coord by 0.25 each frame, the y-coord by 0.25 every 4 frames (or when the x-coord becomes 0.)
replace the contents of the buffer with the uv-coords constructed from: x, x + 0.25, y, y + 0.25

You can either rebuild the enture buffer by clearing it, putting the array and rewinding it. Or you can use putFloat(int pos, float value) to replace existing entries in the buffer. The latter is likely more resource conservative.

Comment: I kind of figured that, but what would the code for that look like?

Comment: You can prepopulate an array with all the possible UV coordinates. Then you store an int as index and step forward each frame. Or you can store each uv-coord as a float and increase them each frame. Many possibilities. The implementation depends on what best suits the rest of your architecture.

Comment: ok, so in your first example, how would you update that in the draw method? would it just be changing the coordinate array, and then calling     uvBuffer.put(coordinateArray)?

Comment: Yes, but you would most likely have another array with only the four items you want to put there. So: uvBuffer.clear(), uvBuffer.put(fourItemArray), uvBuffer.rewind(). The first array is only for looking up the values to put in the second array.

Comment: Updated the answer. I would probably go for solution 2.

Comment: I think I understand the concept, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out what that looks like in code (I'm really new to OpenGL). So, would you simply be modifying the array by adding to the x and y values and then resetting them, and then using uvBuffer.clear(), uvBuffer.put(4uvCoordinateArray), uvBuffer.rewind() every time?

Comment: Yes. It may not be optimal from a memory perspective, recreating the buffer. Also, it's actually 8 elements in the buffer since there are 4 coordinates.

Comment: I'll probably use this temporarily then, but just to point me in the right direction, what would be the optimal way?

Comment: I'm thinking of using putFloat(int index, float value).